# How to add a column based on certain date range with type

Tags: sql

I hv two tables:-

```
First Table:-
EFF_DATE     RATE   CURRENCY    TYPE
20110101     1.286  USD         1
20110101     1.300  USD         2
20110201     1.275  USD         1
20110201     1.290  USD         2
20110301     1.275  USD         1
20110301     1.285  USD         2
20110401     1.260  USD         1
20110401     1.270  USD         2
20110501     1.225  USD         1
20110501     1.230  USD         2
```

2nd Table:-

```
PO_NO   TRANS_DATE  ACCT_DATE   SUPP_NO CURRENCY     LOCAL_AMT 
1000068 20110114    20110115    S016    USD          16,500.00 
1000070 20110214    20110215    S016    USD           7,660.00 
1000072 20110317    20110322    S025    USD           1,080.00 
1000132 20110314    20110315    S037    USD           3,500.00 
1000133 20110414    20110415    S038    USD          14,500.00
```

Based on ACCT_DATE & TYPE = 1, I wish to add a RATE column & the result should look like this:-

```
PO_NO   TRANS_DATE  ACCT_DATE   SUPP_NO CURRENCY     LOCAL_AMT  RATE
1000068 20110114    20110115    S016    USD          16,500.00  1.286
1000070 20110214    20110215    S016    USD           7,660.00  1.275
1000072 20110317    20110322    S025    USD           1,080.00  1.275
1000132 20110314    20110315    S037    USD           3,500.00  1.275
1000133 20110414    20110415    S038    USD          14,500.00  1.26
1000170 20110531    20110531    S016    USD          15,400.00  1.225
```

I used the below SQL to run but for some reasons, it just keep looping without any output:-

```
SELECT st.*, ft.rate
FROM second_table st
LEFT JOIN first_table ft 
    ON (MONTH(acct_date) = MONTH(eff_date) AND YEAR(acct_date) = YEAR(eff_date) )
where ft.TYPE=1
```

Pls help.

Thanks.

Comment: Are the effective dates always guaranteed to be the 1st of their respective months?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Not very large. If I remove ft.TYPE=1,
>   it will generate the result almost
>   immediately.

Based on your comment above you need to put an index on ft.TYPE

You could also set up the query like this which might improve how the optimizer runs the query

```
SELECT st.*, ft.rate
FROM second_table st
LEFT JOIN first_table ft 
    ON ft.TYPE=1 AND MONTH(acct_date) = MONTH(eff_date) AND YEAR(acct_date) = YEAR(eff_date)
```

Also, are the dates stored as strings or as datetime values.  If they are stored as strings you should do a string compare instead of coverting to datetimes and then extracting the month and year.

Answer (score 0):

How large are your tables? Your joining on an agrigate function so it will be very slow if the tables are large

Comment: Not very large. If I remove ft.TYPE=1, it will generate the result almost immediately.